# hyperlinking the table header and making it open in new Window

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, curl

I am working on website trying to get Html source of remote page (the source mainly formed of html tables and each table has header)

i am using the code below to get the source of this remote page:

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://remotesite/pages/page1.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo str_replace('</h3><table','<table',$doc->saveHTML());
?>
```

I want to make every table header as link when clicked it open new page containg this table

any ideas how to deal with this

Comment: and of course you have permission from the remote site.

Comment: yes i have permission

Comment: Said remote site isn't dynamic? It would be easier to have them push out an XML or RSS feed then secure it to your domain.

Comment: @Imperative the remote site is dynamic and content upadte very hour